# Can I (or someone else) vote to re-open a closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic

I recently wanted to answer [This question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/26559/what-are-some-potential-issues-this-character-could-go-through), but as I was writing my answer I got a message that the question had been closed due to being off-topic in the "what to write" category (some seemed to disagree on this), but the question wasn't too difficult to answer without giving "what to write"-answers. Can I edit the question to stay more on-topic or can the author? And would that re-open the question?

I'm still new to this platform, so I have yet to learn the exact policies and structures of everything.. I just thought it was a shame that the question was closed since the broad question within it was relatable to many in my opinion, including myself.

Comment: If you can help with an edit, please do so!  (See my comment on Standback's answer for more.)

Comment: I have now edited the question (first edit) to better suit the general purpose of the forum, while trying to avoid making the answers seem out of place.

Comment: Nice edit!  Thank you for your help; it should now be in the reopen review queue.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad to hear that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast reopen votes once you get the ["close and reopen questions privilege"](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions); on this site, that means reaching a reputation of 500 (other sites will have different bars).

The author can edit their question to bring it on topic, if they want to. Discussion in the comments can often help them figure out how to edit the question into something that will be reopened.

You can suggest an edit as well (every post should have an "edit" link under it). Your suggested edit will be reviewed by veteran users, who are also likely to vote to reopen if they feel you've fixed it. So, this is one of the most helpful things you can do to get a question reopened -- bringing it to a position where it *can* be reopened. (But, you do need to take care not turn the question into something entirely different than the original poster asked -- that would be unhelpful to the OP, and would make existing answers confusing.)

See more details on editing [over here](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

And, welcome to the site, and enjoy!

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, very much this -- if you can propose an edit that fixes the problem that people cited in closing the question, *do it*.  Your edit will be reviewed (until your rep goes up some), and especially if the question is marked "on hold" instead of "closed", an edit automatically sends it to the review queue for reopen voters.